# Variable limits (function of x) in a definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals, leibniz-integral-rule

I am stuck in a concept of Definite Integration.

Let us say we have a function that goes like ${f(x) = \int_0^x e^{x-t} f(t) \,dt}$

Now I wanted to know that if I put $x=0$, will the limit range from $0$ to $0$ (hence value is also $0$). Also will the $x$ inside integral attain the value $0$. Also let $x=1$, then will the limits now range from $0$ to $1$ and the integral now becomes ${f(x) = \int_0^1 e^{1-t} f(t) \,dt}$ ? Please explain how this works.

Comment: Edited with a query on example for x=1 to clearly understand the concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression on the right works the way it's written. The value of the integral depends on the value of $x$. For each particular value it's a number. You can interpret that number as the area under the curve $e^{x-t}f(t)$ for $t$ in the interval $[0,x]$. It is indeed $0$ when $x=0$.

Writing
$$
{f(x) = \int_0^1 e^{1-t} f(t) \,dt}
$$
makes no sense. What substituting $1$ for $x$ calculates is the value of $f$ at $x=1$. That's the ordinary integral
$$
{f(1) = \int_0^1 e^{1-t} f(t) \,dt}
$$

If you really mean to have $f(x)$ on the left and also as part of the integrand then the equation will work for some functions $f$ and not others. To "solve" that equation for the unknown function $f$ you can differentiate the right side (correctly, using the fundamental theorem of calculus and taking into account the fact that there's an $x$ in the integrand). That will lead to a differential equation you can try to solve for $f$.

Comment: So here $x$ acts as a variable or $t$ ? or both? Like if i put $x=t$ in f(x), will the exponential term become $e^0$ inside integrand?

Comment: No, There is no "" in the integral that you can use outside the integral. It's the "variable of integration", Do you think you could use the value of or substitute a numerical value for  in $\int_0^1^2$ and preserve the meaning of the integral?

Comment: This means x can take any numerical constant value for the integral to make sense (area under the curve) but not the variable of integration itself as it won't make any sense. (This might sound silly but I was seriously stuck on this from a considerable time).